# How to Handle Proxies within Carto's Python Import API framework

Tags: python, carto, import, batch, proxy

I am attempting to programmatically upload new data sets (tables) to Carto with the Carto Import API Python SDK. Unfortunately, I am doing this behind a proxy which is blocking me from successfully reaching the Carto API endpoint.

I have experimented with the requests and urllib libraries to successfully circumvent the proxy block, but I am not familiar with how to implement this same proxy handling within the framework of Carto's import python module. I have the proxy address and a username that can successfully connect through it.

The following code is what I am using to attempt to connect and upload a sample data set.

```
from carto.datasets import DatasetManager
from carto.auth import APIKeyAuthClient

USERNAME = '{username_placeholder}'

USR_BASE_URL = "https://{user}.carto.com/".format(user=USERNAME)

auth_client = APIKeyAuthClient(api_key="{api_placeholder}", base_url=USR_BASE_URL)

Local = r'C:\temp\carto\carto_test.zip'

dataset_manager = DatasetManager(auth_client)
dataset = dataset_manager.create(Local)
```

The error I receive when running this code is as follows:

> carto.exceptions.CartoException: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='{placeholder}.carto.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/imports/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Would anyone be able to assist in adding functionality for proxy handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CARTO Python SDK uses `requests` library, which follows a pretty standard practice to honor proxies declared as environment variable so maybe you should try to export `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`. Example below from library [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:3128"
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:1080"

$ python
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://example.org')
```

Give it a try and if that does not work you may want to create a ticket at the SDK tracker https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-python/issues/new